# File `/i18n/de_DE.csv` not found

Tags: magento2, localisation, debugging

I am using the latest Magento 2.0.2 release and imported the German

```
bin/magento i18n:pack --mode=replace -d source.csv . de_DE
```

When I now open a product page I am getting

```
File "/i18n/de_DE.csv" does not exist
#0 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/File/Csv.php(119): Magento\Framework\File\Csv->getData('/i18n/de_DE.csv')
#1 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php(378): Magento\Framework\File\Csv->getDataPairs('/i18n/de_DE.csv')
#2 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php(272): Magento\Framework\Translate->_getFileData('/i18n/de_DE.csv')
#3 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php(258): Magento\Framework\Translate->loadModuleTranslationByModulesList(Array)
#4 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php(179): Magento\Framework\Translate->_loadModuleTranslation()
#5 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php(240): Magento\Framework\Translate->loadData(NULL, false)
#6 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php(211): Magento\Framework\App\Area->_initTranslate()
#7 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/App/Area.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Area->_loadPart('translate')
#8 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/View/DesignLoader.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\Area->load('translate')
#9 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(38): Magento\Framework\View\DesignLoader->load()
#10 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#13 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 [internal function]: Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#16 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#17 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#20 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#21 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 [internal function]: Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#24 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#25 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 [internal function]: Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#28 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Forward/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#29 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#32 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#33 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#34 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(89): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#37 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#38 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#39 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#41 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#42 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#45 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#46 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#49 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#50 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#52 /home/self/acme/workspace/example.de/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#53 {main}
```

It looks like `\Magento\Framework\Translate::getControllerModuleName` is returning `null`.

The home page rendered using `Magento_Cms` is working.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I am using PHP7.

**edit** This seems also to happen with a fresh `composer install` of my project and without calling bin/magento i18n:pack`

Comment: When I delete `$PROJECTROOT/i18n/de_DE.csv` it seems to work.

Comment: It also is an issue with PHP5, I followed Alex suggestion and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of deleting `i18n` you can create a symlink in `/` to the `$PROJETROOT/i18n` folder